# How are numbers such as thousands or millions pronounced?

Tags: numbers, reading-aloud

How do you pronounce numbers like

375

1846

12361

55732

101223

223440

1326528

Comment: In what context?

Comment: As snailplane notes, they may be pronounced differently depending on where you see them. *1846* could be the year *eighteen forty-six* or the Year of Our Lord *eighteen hundred and forty-six*; part number *one-eight-four-six*; or *one thousand eight hundred [and] forty-six* sheets of paper.

Comment: Assuming basic math with whole numbers, here is a link that will give the *formal* American English pronunciation -- http://www.webmath.com/saynum.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recently mentioned answer to a similar question that in some parts of the English speaking world, people say 'and' after 'hundred':

375: three hundred *and* seventy five

1846: one thousand eight hundred *and* forty six

etc.

Even if the 'and' is as small as 'n': three hundred'n seventy five

Comment: +1 As a U.S. speaker, is very common here to say *and* when pronouncing the final "ones" column. When speaking more informally (e.g. three hundred seventy five), the "and" can be omitted, but is often implied.

Comment: When I was in elementary school our teacher taught us that saying *and* in the whole number portion was flat-out wrong-  one thousand eight hundred forty six.  The *and* is used to include a fractional component-  "and five eighths"   Everybody says *and* but thought I'd at least point out that it's not universally accepted.

Comment: what about millions  numbers.. how many Ands will be there? .e.g .. 3719738 .. will it be " three million and seven hundred nineteen thousands and seven hundred and thirty eight ?

Comment: @Anaksunaman: In my experience, we only use an *and* for the ones column if there is a zero in the tens column.  307 could be "three hundred seven" or "three hundred and seven", but 548 is never "five hundred forty and eight" (though it could perhaps be "five hundred and forty-eight").

Comment: @NateEldrige Yes. "Three hundred seven" (good), "Three hundred seven and seven-eighths" (good), "Three hundred and seven" (informal but acceptable to most). I have never heard "five hundred forty and eight" either.

Comment: @Jocka.M There is usually only one "and" (if at all). For 1,300,248 you would say (properly) "one million, three hundred thousand, two hundred forty-eight" *or* (commonly) "one million, three hundred thousand, two hundred and forty-eight". If there was a fractional component (1,300,248.875) you would use the proper pronunciation followed by "and eight hundred seventy five thousandths", "and seven-eighths", or perhaps "point eight seven five". You likely wouldn't say "one million, three hundred thousand, two hundred and forty-eight and seven-eights".

Comment: Argh! Me and my terrible typos! :-) I did mean to say "When speaking more formally". Saying "and" is far more common, but yes, good teachers (and mathematicians) will properly tell you to say "three hundred seventy five".

Comment: Every time I have heard USEng speakers say numbers (in person, on radio, on tv, in movies etc), it has been (as far as I remember) without 'and'. Perhaps with word processing, we use fractions less and decimals more. I would say 123 1/2 as 'one hundred'n twenty three and a half' and 123.5 as 'one hundred'n twenty three point five. I don't process '.875' as 'seven eighths' (but maybe vice versa).

Answer (score 3):

It's very easy.

You just say how many thousands followed by the word "thousand", so if you have 300 * 1000 then you just say

> **three hundred** *thousand*

You do the exact same thing for millions and up.

If you don't have a clean number of thousands, then just say the remainder after that like normal.  here are some examples:

- 375:  **Three hundred seventy five**
- 1846:  **one** *thousand* **eight hundred fourty six**.
- 12361:  **twelve** *thousand* **three hundred sixty one**.
- 1326528:  **one** *million* **three hundred twenty six** *thousand* **five hundred twenty eight**

etc...

Comment: it would be helpful if continue to say all examples especially those high numbers .. Thanks!