# When to use 'and' with numbers?

Tags: grammar, conjunctions, numbers

let's say we wan to say 6879 out loud

Would it be

> six thousand eight hundred seventy-nine
>
> six thousand *and* eight hundred seventy-nine
>
> six thousand *and* eight hundred *and* seventy-nine

What about larger numbers?

Comment: Also http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/30350/how-are-numbers-such-as-thousands-or-millions-pronounced

Comment: @James K Not really useful link as the article proposes that and should not be used then we have this comment later on. Good answer - except for one thing... In BrE it is "nine hundred and ninety nine thousand, nine hundred and ninety nine" "One hundred and twenty three million…"

Comment: Yes,  I've just written my own answer to that question.  That is a better approach than to answer this duplicate here. See the question is a duplicate, even if you don't agree with the upvoted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A.

6879= **six thousand eight hundred **and** seventy-nine**[6,8,(79)]

68796879 = sixty eight million, seven hundred **and** ninety six thousand, eight hundred **and** seventy-nine**.  [68,7(96),8(79)]

It is the Hundred that cause the problem (and) as speech is based on two decimal counts but figures are grouped based on three decimal counts.

Comment: Note that some regions (USA, I think; possibly more) habitually omit the "and" after "hundred".  Without locale information in the question, it's hard to give the right answer.

Comment: Agreed; but the English use the "and" and it is ELL :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining!  
I understood, but can you please chech whether this spelling of '879,123,456,789' is correct?      
Eight hundred and seventy-nine billion, one hundred and twenty-three million, four hundred and fifty-six thousand, seven hundred and eighty-nine thousand      
And also, you wrote 'sixty eight million, seven hundred and ninety six thousand, eight hundred and seventy-nine'.          
Shouldn't it be 'sixty eight million***s***, seven hundred***s*** and ninety six thousand***s***, eight hundred***s*** and seventy-nine'?

Comment: No "s". "Twelve thousand years ago, our ancestors were primitive savages living in caves" We only use the "s" with not precise counts "Accommodation needs to be found for thousands of homeless families" ie. vague amounts.